# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when executing StoredProcedure in java

Tags: java, mysql

I try to call a stored procedure that have out parameters

My code is:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{CALL banco.sppro_prepagoprestamo(?,?,?,?,NOW(),?,?)}");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
callableStatement.setString(3,cuenta);
callableStatement.setString(4,monto);
callableStatement.setString(5,usuarioIdLog);
callableStatement.setString(6,tipoPago);
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
String msg = callableStatement.getString(1);
int codigo = callableStatement.getInt(2);
```

but when it execute the line

```
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

It throws the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

I was searching in different web pages to solve this problem, but I found by myself that changing the database connection from:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
conn    =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banco?user=user&password=pass");
```

to:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
conn    =   DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
```

solve the problem, now I want to create a pool connection in tomcat so I change the connection to :

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/BancoDB");
conn= dataSource.getConnection();
```

but again it throws the same error, can anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.setOutParams(CallableStatement.java:2088)
    com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.executeUpdate(CallableStatement.java:822)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    org.apache.jsp.credito.procesos.creproprepagoprestarjeta.creProPrepagoCtaVirtualGraba_jsp._jspService(creProPrepagoCtaVirtualGraba_jsp.java:1455)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: how did you define your datasource then?

Comment: What do you mean??, I only modify the context.xml of the tomcat, the connection is working, this only fails when I try to call a StoredProcedure that have out parameters

Comment: show the stacktrace then

Comment: I added to my question, thanks for you help.

Comment: Which version of the mysql driver do you use?

Comment: I am using the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in the mysql driver it has been fixed in `5.1.13` more details [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43576), so to fix your bug simply upgrade it to the latest version.

Comment: Yes that works, I only upgrade to a new one and it fix the problem, thanks for your help.